# Displaying HTML in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I need to display `<img src="http://my.pic/test/rg/pict.png" />` from `items`.`img`

But when `res.write(rows[0].img, 'utf8');`,

I see  in browser:

`<img style="display: none !important;" src="http://my.pic/test/rg/pict.png" />`

How do I fix `style="display: none !important;"`?

```
 express = require('express'), app = express();
 var mysql = require('mysql');

 app.listen(8080);

 mysql.connect = function(req, res, next){
    var connect = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'person',
    password : 'ppasw',
    database : 'db1'
    });

  return connect;
 }

server.get(new RegExp('/img'), function(req, res, next){
var db =mysql.connect(); 

 db.connect();
 db.query("use `bd1`");
 db.query("SELECT `img` FROM `items` WHERE `id`='" +    intval(req.query.id) + "'",   

   function (err, rows, fields) {

     res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
     res.write(rows[0].img, 'utf8');
     res.end();

   });
      db.end();
});
```

*-*-*-*-*
I find problem - Adblock plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add this debug code before the res.write part ?

```
console.log(rows[0].img)
```

My best guess is that the style attribute is already in the database.

My second best guess is that you might have some javascript running in your browser which hides broken images.

Comment: in DB `<img src="http://my.pic/test/rg/pict.png" />`
why is displayed style? i no understand

Comment: In chrome, can you right click on your html page and then pick "view source" and check how the image looks without javascript applied ?

Comment: I need to do to be displayed without `style="display: none !important;"`

Comment: I think there is some javascript adding the `style="display: none !important;"` part in the browser. If you can post the whole html we might figure out whats going on. Without more information i cannot help you.

Comment: I try chrome incognito, my result : `<img src="http://my.pic/test/rg/pict.png" />`

Comment: Then you might have a plugin installed which hides broken images. Does  `http://my.pic/test/rg/pict.png` shows an image when you put it directly in the location bar ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the information on the database, you may have to construct the HTML. If you're only putting the URL to the image in there, it's not going to work right. You might have to do something like:

```
res.write('<html><body><img src="' + rows[0].img + '" /></body></html>');
```

If the database has all of the HTML already stored (I suggest not doing that) and you don't have any extensions hiding broken images, you're going to have to have some client side Javascript to unhide the image.

Comment: `var dc = decodeURI(text);`

`var body = '<html><body>' + dec + '</body></html>';`

`res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");`

`res.write(body, 'utf8');`


displayed `<img src="http://my.pic/test/rg/pict.png" style="display: none !important;">`

Comment: If you go to http://my.pic/test/rg/pict.png in a browser, does that appear correctly?